# Is there a format to cast a string column into a timestamp in a pyspark dataframe?

Tags: pyspark, timestamp

I have a pyspark dataframe column with values like this:

```
+----------------------------+
|                 date_string|
+----------------------------+
|   22JUL2020:20:35:36.009269|
|   22JUL2020:20:41:45.483747|
```

I want to cast this string column into a timestamp so I'm using the follow code:

```py
df.withColumn('date_timestamp', to_timestamp('date_string', 'ddMMMyyyy:HH:mm:ss'))
```

```
+----------------------------+----------------------------+
|                 date_string|              date_timestamp|
+----------------------------+----------------------------+
|   22JUL2020:20:35:36.009269|          22JUL2020:20:35:36|
|   22JUL2020:20:41:45.483747|          22JUL2020:20:41:45|
```

What format should I use to not lose the numbers after the seconds? I've tried the following formats but always get null:

```py
df.withColumn('date_timestamp', to_timestamp('date_string', 'ddMMMyyyy:HH:mm:ss.nnnnnn'))
df.withColumn('date_timestamp', to_timestamp('date_string', 'ddMMMyyyy:HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'))
df.withColumn('date_timestamp', to_timestamp('date_string', 'ddMMMyyyy:HH:mm:ss.SSS'))
```

```
+----------------------------+-------------------------+
|                 date_string|           date_timestamp|
+----------------------------+-------------------------+
|   22JUL2020:20:35:36.009269|                     null|
|   22JUL2020:20:41:45.483747|                     null|
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `SSSSSS` i.e. `S` repeated for exact number of times as that of number of digits for milliseconds in the string:

```py
df.withColumn('date_timestamp', F.to_timestamp('date_string', 'ddMMMyyyy:HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'))
```

Full working example:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ["22JUL2020:20:35:36.009269"],
        ["22JUL2020:20:41:45.483747"],
    ],
    ["date_string"]
)

df = df.withColumn('date_timestamp', F.to_timestamp('date_string', 'ddMMMyyyy:HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'))

+-------------------------+--------------------------+
|date_string              |date_timestamp            |
+-------------------------+--------------------------+
|22JUL2020:20:35:36.009269|2020-07-22 20:35:36.009269|
|22JUL2020:20:41:45.483747|2020-07-22 20:41:45.483747|
+-------------------------+--------------------------+


df.select("date_timestamp").limit(1).collect()[0]["date_timestamp"].microsecond

>> 9269


df.select("date_timestamp").limit(2).collect()[1]["date_timestamp"].microsecond

>> 483747
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the precision of each `microsecond` as well to fully parse the date format that you have as an input within `TO_TIMESTAMP`

For extensive list of available parsing options you can refer - [DateTime Patters](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html)

#### TO TIMESTAMP

```
sql.sql("""
SELECT
    date_inp,
    TO_TIMESTAMP(date_inp, "ddMMMyyyy:HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS") as date_parsed
FROM (
    SELECT "22JUL2020:20:35:36.009269" as date_inp
    UNION ALL
    SELECT "22JUL2020:20:41:45.483747" as date_inp
)
""").show(truncate=False)

+-------------------------+--------------------------+
|date_inp                 |date_parsed               |
+-------------------------+--------------------------+
|22JUL2020:20:35:36.009269|2020-07-22 20:35:36.009269|
|22JUL2020:20:41:45.483747|2020-07-22 20:41:45.483747|
+-------------------------+--------------------------+
```